# Why doesn't this code copy and paste subtract?

Tags: excel, vba

I expected this code to copy and paste subtract. It does copy, and if I stop the program manually and paste, it pastes fine. However, it does not seem to want to activate the worksheet (name is correct) and paste-subtract like it should. What's going on?

For i = currwbk.Range("A2").Value To currwbk.Range("C2").Value

```
wks = currwbk.Range("S" & i).Value

Debug.Print diff.FullName

Application.CutCopyMode = True

cons.Sheets(wks).Range("U12:Y84").Copy
diff.Sheets(wks).Activate
diff.Sheets(wks).Range("U12").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlSubtract, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("G5").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: How get value the currwbk ? In any case it is better to hane two variables  vFrom = currwbk.Range("A2").Value        vTo =  currwbk.Range("C2").Value and  For i = vFrom to  vTo ...

Comment: You don't give a complete code. Anyway, by the look of your code, your diff and cons variable are workbooks. Your currwbk is a sheet. And I guess, currwbk is a sheet of cons. Assumed my guessing is correct, after you set diff variable (which is something like `set diff = workbooks("blablabla")`, if you add a line `diff.activate` and step run it while the active workbook is cons, does it activate the diff (workbook blablabla) ? Please CMIIW.